# TFS (AzureDevOps) 2015 C# Get Variables used in Build

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops

I created some variables in a new vNext build template (TFS 2015 Update 3), which are partially modified during the build.
I can access the (unmodified) variables via the build definition:

```
VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(Helper.uri, new VssCredentials());
var vNextBuildClient = connection.GetClient<BuildHttpClient>();
var buildDef = (vNextBuildClient.GetDefinitionAsync(myProject, myId).Result) as BuildDefinition;
// buildDef.Variables contains all variables
```

However, I can't get the variables of a specific build.

```
var buildsvNext = await vNextBuildClient.GetBuildsAsync(myProject, listOfIDs, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 5, null, null);
var currentBuilds = buildsvNext.Where(b => b.Definition.Id == definition2.Id).ToList();
foreach (var build in currentBuilds) {
    // no variables here
}
```

How can I get the variables that belong to a build? Or do I have to explicitly store the variables somewhere during a build?

Edit: I found the following Q/A on
[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30793882/programmatically-access-tfs-build-output)

Unfortunately I could not get the Artifact folder with both solutions:

```
https://{AccountName}.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/{TeamProject}/_apis/build/builds/{BuildId}/artifacts/drop?%24format=zip

http://{MyTFSServer}/{TeamProjectCollection}/{TeamProject}/_api/_build/ItemContent?buildUri=vstfs:///Build/Build/{BuildId}&path=/drop&__v=5
```

Comment: I suspect they're stored in the Build's propertiesCollection: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#propertiescollection

Comment: artefacts are definitely not what you are looking for

Comment: if the variables can be set on queue time, you can aferwards get their values from the "parameters"-field of the build json

Comment: @D.J. I'm afraid not. The variables are set automatically during the build.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround:

I save all variables with a Powershell script into an XML file in the artifacts and then read this file with the appropiate REST API command.

[TFS Rest API for TFS 2015 - Get build artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/previous-apis/build/builds?view=tfs-2015#get-build-artifacts)

```
GET https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/artifacts
```